# How to parent constraint props to objects created by array Modifiers

Tags: animation, modifiers, curve-modifier

I have create a conveyer belt using array modifiers and curve modifiers. I want to parents items to the conveyer. [image]. What are my options on this...

Comment: you could simply give a Follow Path constraint to your objects in order to make them follow the conveyer belt, you'll just need to make sure that they'll go the same speed as the belt

Comment: do you really want to parent your objects? This does not look realistic.... or do you want a rigid body simulation with a conveyor belt?

Comment: I suspect there are some details left out of this that would let people (like me) be confident with a solution.  The problem isn't the array, it's whatever method you're using to path the array.  Can you share a file?

Comment: Thanks moonboots your solutions works

Comment: Hi Chris i have not looked into rigid bodies would explore that option as well .

Comment: Hi Nathan , i am using curve modifier and animation keys to move the conveyor …